# alias required in select list of cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I m getting an error as when I compiled the below code as alias required in select list of the cursor.

```
   Create Or Replace PROCEDURE pr_no_debit is
     Cursor c_Today(From_date date, To_Date date) is
     Select Today from sttm_dates where today between From_Date and To_Date;

        cursor c_no_debit is
      Select a.* , b.* from STTM_NO_DEBIT_customer a , STTM_FIN_CYCLE b where a.Fin_Cycle = b.Fin_Cycle ;

   l_No_Debit_List   STTM_NO_DEBIT_CUSTOMER%ROWTYPE;

   begin
     For i_indx in c_Today(l_No_Debit_List.From_Date,l_No_Debit_List.To_Date) 
       Loop  
         for j_indx in c_no_debit 

     loop

       update sttm_cust_account set ac_stat_no_Dr='Y' where account_class=j_index.account_class;
     end loop;

   End Loop;

     -- At the end of the period Change No_Debit to 'N'

   End pr_no_debit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be to split the cursor into two parts, though giving alias to respective columns shall be sufficient under the case:

Cursor  c_no_debit :
c_no_debit_1: Based on table STTM_NO_DEBIT_customer a
c_no_debit_2: Based on table STTM_FIN_CYCLE b

Through parameterized cursor pass value of of cursor_1 into cursor_2.

Answer (score 0):

Tables `STTM_NO_DEBIT_CUSTOMER` and `STTM_FIN_CYCLE` both have a column named `FIN_CYCLE`, so when the PL/SQL compiler tries to construct the record `j_indx` from `c_no_debit`, it gets something like this:

```
( fin_cycle      number
, from_date      date
, to_date        date
, account_class  varchar2(20)
, fin_cycle      number
, ...
```

which is invalid because a record can't have two fields with the same name.

Change `c_no_debit` to specify only the columns you need, for example:

```
cursor c_no_debit is
    select a.account_class
    from   sttm_no_debit_customer a
           join sttm_fin_cycle b on b.fin_cycle = a.fin_cycle;
```

(and maybe other columns - I don't have your schema and I don't know what it needs to do)